# MS Fake gives a compilation Error when faking a library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-fakes

I'm trying to create a fakes library for one libraries.  However it is giving me a compilation error that I don't know how to fix:

The type 'TEntity' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'LogicBase.Save(IEnumerable)'.  There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TEntity' to 'Common.Components.EntityBase'

I'm not sure what I have to do to resolve this.  Can someone tell me what I can try?

Comment: Your question is about compilation error but does not contain any code. How are we supposed to answer?